# SharePoint on line Analytic report

Tags: sharepoint, report

When gnerate Auditing Reports for a site collection on our SharePoint tenant for 8 months from the begining of year till now -form Jan to August- it display two months only May and June.
Any one can help me on solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce the issue in my SharePoint.

Whether you use audit logs in the site collection or Security & Compliance Center?

I suggest you get audit logs in the Security & Compliance Center or through PowerShell.

Reference:

[SharePoint Online: How to View Audit Log Reports in Security & Compliance Center?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/09/sharepoint-online-search-audit-logs-in-security-compliance-center.html)